# Carousel breaking in ie7

Tags: javascript, jquery

Something's wrong with my carousel on ie7, it's just showing as a list, whereas on other browsers it's working perfectly.

[image: On ff]

[image: On ie7]

http://goo.gl/HR8RM

I have removed all javascript conflicts but still it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

With your `<li>`'s that make up each set of data in the carousel, try:

```
display: inline;
```

And remove:

```
float: left;
```

I would then make the following `<div>`:

```
display: block;
float: left;
width: blah;
margin: blah;
```